# How to inner join multiple columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am trying to write a stored procedure for a keyword search. The way we have our DB set up.

There is a `Genres` table that has `Genre names` and `Genre ID's`, then there is a `Genrebridge` table which has `genreID1, GenreID2, GenreID3, GenreID4, GenreID5, SongID, AlbumID` and `ArtistID`.

How do I inner join each of the `GenreID` fields, so the `Genre name` is linked to the `Genre Bridge` table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_album_search_keyword_AlbumNameANDArtistName]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @albumname  varchar(255),
    @artistname varchar(255)
)
As
Begin
Select 
    Distinct a.AlbumTitle, art.ArtistName, a.AvgRatingNBR, a.OriginalPrice, a.DiscountPrice
FROM 
    Albums a 
    inner join Artists art on a.ArtistID = art.ArtistID
    inner join GenreBridge gb on gb.AlbumID = a.AlbumID
    inner join Genres g on g.GenreID = gb.GenreID1
    inner join genres g on g.GenreID = gb.genreID2
    inner join genres g on g.GenreID = gb.GenreID3
    inner join genres g on g.GenreID = gb.GenreID4
    inner join genres g on g.GenreID = gb.GenreID5

    where a.AlbumTitle like '%' + @albumname + '%' 
    and art.ArtistName like '%' + @artistname + '%'
End
```

Comment: Does this code run?  And, if so, what output do you get?

Comment: when I try and execute the procedure I get the following error: Invalid object name 'g'.

edit: i believe its the second time i declare genres as g

Comment: use different aliases instead of `g`, like `g1`, `g2`, etc

Comment: is that the best route to go?

Comment: Yes you are making the basic synatax error using same alias name. You can use the `JOIN` with `OR` clause on multiple columns.

Comment: @StuartLC can you explain this further? 
The requirements for this project require that each song/album/artist must have atleast 1 genre and can have up to 5 genres...

as I have the table set up right now, would i do 1 inner join, and 4 left joins?

Comment: I've posted the table redesign as an answer. Also note no need to join to genre in your proc in its current form.

Comment: `inner join genres g on (g.GenreID=gb.GenreID1 or g.GenreID=gb.GenreID2 or …)` , but there's really better alternatives, probably suggested in the answers below (which I have not looked at yet)

Answer (score 5):

Other than using the same aliases as noted in the comments, the table `GenreBridge` isn't correctly normalized. To normalize the table, it would be better to have a single `GenreID` column on the table, and then insert as many rows as needed to model all genres of an album. This would also lift the arbitrary restriction on the number of genres per album.

As a side note, your original procedure doesn't seem to use `Genre` at all (in either the select list or where filter), so hence no need to join to it, and you won't need the `DISTINCT`.

As you've noted, you now face issues with joins depending on the number of valid genre columns present on `AlbumGenre`

Assuming you've used INT primary keys throughout, I would normalize the table `GenreBridge` to be a many:many link table between Albums and Genres, and at the same time rename it `AlbumGenre` to better reflect the many:many convention, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AlbumGenre
(
   AlbumId INT NOT NULL,
   GenreId INT NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT PK_AlbumnGenre PRIMARY KEY(AlbumId, GenreId),
   CONSTRAINT FK_AlbumnGenre_Albumn FOREIGN KEY(AlbumId) REFERENCES Albums(AlbumId),
   CONSTRAINT FK_AlbumnGenre_Genre FOREIGN KEY(GenreId) REFERENCES Genres(GenreId)
);
```

The restriction that there can be between 1 and 5 genres will need to be enforced by your program (i.e. before inserting an `AlbumnGenre` record link, ensure that there are less than 5 rows for this albumn.)

To list all genres of an album, you would just need to join `Albumn` to the `AlbumGenre` and filter by `AlbumnId` in the where clause (it will return as many rows as there are genres).

As mentioned, no need for `DISTINCT` or joining to Genre:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_album_search_keyword_AlbumNameANDArtistName]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @albumname  varchar(255),
    @artistname varchar(255)
)
As
Begin
Select a.AlbumTitle, art.ArtistName, a.AvgRatingNBR, a.OriginalPrice, a.DiscountPrice
FROM 
    Albums a 
    inner join Artists art on a.ArtistID = art.ArtistID
    where a.AlbumTitle like '%' + @albumname + '%' 
    and art.ArtistName like '%' + @artistname + '%'
End
```

Comment: so i would need to have 3 separate bridge tables in this scenario, correct?

Comment: No, just the one `AlbumGenre` table. If an album has 3 genres, then there will be 3 rows in `AlbumGenre` for the same `AlbumId`. Joining 'once' between `Album` and `AlbumGenre` and `Genre` and filtering by `Album.AlbumId` will yield 3 rows.

Comment: sorry, my question was vague. @stuartLC, I believe I would need to create a SongGenre table and an ArtistGenre table in my db as well and link in similar fashion as you describe above, 

I was previously trying to have one bridge table with these fields:
    GenreID SongID AlbumID ArtistID. Is this bad db design?

Comment: It sounds like you have a complicated model in mind (i.e. Albums have Songs, each song can be a different Genre - can an album have more than one artist?). However, `ArtistGenre` sounds like a derived concept, e.g. if most of the songs by an Artist are `BlueGrass` then the artist could be dubbed primarily `BlueGrass`. You could also group all songs by the same artist by the Song's genre and then get a count / histogram of genres for an artist. Either way, I wouldn't model a new table for `ArtistGenre` - at worst, I would make this a table which uses one of the above derivation / assumptions.

Comment: they way our requirements are set up, songid is our most unique field (i.e. most songs belong to an album, however some do not. songs and albums cannot have more than one artist) so I created SongGenre how you describe above. Thank you soooo much for your help @stuartLC!!!

Answer (score 1):

@StuartLC gives some good feedback that I would seriously consider.  But if you intend to leave your database schema as is, then this query should work:

```
SELECT          a.AlbumTitle, 
                art.ArtistName, 
                a.AvgRatingNBR, 
                a.OriginalPrice, 
                a.DiscountPrice,
                g1.GenreName,
                g2.GenreName,
                g3.GenreName,
                g4.GenreName,
                g5.GenreName
FROM            Albums a 
INNER JOIN      Artists art on a.ArtistID = art.ArtistID
INNER JOIN      GenreBridge gb on gb.AlbumID = a.AlbumID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Genres g1 on g1.GenreID = gb.GenreID1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Genres g2 on g2.GenreID = gb.GenreID2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Genres g3 on g3.GenreID = gb.GenreID3
LEFT OUTER JOIN Genres g4 on g4.GenreID = gb.GenreID4
LEFT OUTER JOIN Genres g5 on g5.GenreID = gb.GenreID5
WHERE           a.AlbumTitle like ('%' + @albumname + '%')
    AND         art.ArtistName like ('%' + @artistname + '%')
```

Comment: thanks raj! I just finished discussing it with my group, we're going to follow @stuartLC's model and normalize the table.